# Check if an object equals another object through a transitive relationship

Tags: c#, recursion

I have a class ValuePair with two properties defined in it:

```
public class ValuePair: IEquatable<ValuePair>
{
    public string value1;
    public string value2;

    public ValuePair(string v1, string v1)
    {
        this.value1 = v1;
        this.value2 = v2;
    }
    ...
}
```

I have some test data in a List as defined below:

```
List<ValuePair> pairs = new ValuePair<ValuePair>();
pairs.Add(new ValuePair("A","B"));
pairs.Add(new ValuePair("A","C"));
pairs.Add(new ValuePair("B","C"));
pairs.Add(new ValuePair("C","D"));
```

My goal is to keep pairs[0] and pairs[1] because the pairs "A,B" and "A,C" are unique, but to remove pair[2] because the relationship "B,C" has already been captured in the first two relationships.  pairs[3] should remain since the "C,D" relationship is unique.

I have a feeling the solution to this problem will be recursive, which is something that I have very little experience with.  I started going down a path of adding a method to the class ValuePair that looks something like this:

```
public string EqualToEither(ValuePair v)
        {
            if (v.value1 == this.value1 || v.value1 == this.value2)
                return v.value1;
            else if (v.value2 == this.value1 || v.value2 == this.value2)
                return v.value2;
            else
                return string.Empty;
        }
```

I've started to try to use the above method inside of a function like this, but I am getting hung up on what to do next:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < pairs.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int j = pairs.Count - 1; j >= 0; j--)
            {
                if (pairs[j].EqualToEither(pairs[i]) != string.Empty)
                {
                    pairs[j].EqualToEither(pairs[i]);
                }
                else
                {
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }
```

I feel like I am close but still unable to get it.  Can anyone please offer some guidance?  If I'm approaching this the completely wrong way please let me know, thank you!

Comment: It sounds like what you want is a [spanning tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanning_tree_(mathematics)).  If each item represents a node, and each pair of items represents an edge, then your list of pairs represents a graph.  So an algorithm to find the spanning tree of a graph should get what you want.

Comment: If you don't care about which pair to keep a spanning tree is indeed the way to go, but if you have stronger requirements, a standard spanning tree algorithm might not fully serve your needs. To me it's not really clear from the question what you expect.

Comment: What do you want pairs.Add(new ValuePair("C","B")); to do in this example? I ask because it matters a lot if you care about direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to solve a similar problem recently, here is how I solved it:

Transitivity is best represented, in my opinion, by grouping interrelated elements together.

For each pair you have to validate if it already belongs to a group (both values are already in the group) or if it extends the relation of a group (only one of the values belong to the group).

In the case it does not belong in any group, it becomes a new group.

In the case both values belong in different groups then you have to merge them.

As mentioned, this is closely related to a spanning tree.

---

One solution could be to use HashSets to represent the transitivity of your relations (I did not use HashSets in my case, there are many possible solutions).
Each HashSet would represent a group of interrelated elements.

Example implementation using HashSets:

```
List<ValuePair> pairs = new List<ValuePair>();
pairs.Add(new ValuePair("A", "B"));
pairs.Add(new ValuePair("A", "C"));
pairs.Add(new ValuePair("B", "C"));
pairs.Add(new ValuePair("C", "D"));

List<ValuePair> uniquePairs = new List<ValuePair>(); 
// this list is not really needed if all you care about 
//   is getting the resulting groups

List<HashSet<string>> sets = new List<HashSet<string>>();

foreach (ValuePair pair in pairs)
{
    int value1Set = -1;
    int value2Set = -1;

    for (int i = 0; i < sets.Count; i++)
    {
        HashSet<string> set = sets[i];

        if (set.Contains(pair.value1))
            value1Set = i;
        if (set.Contains(pair.value2))
            value2Set = i;
    }

    if (value1Set == -1 && value2Set == -1)
    {
        // we have a new set
        sets.Add(new HashSet<string> {pair.value1, pair.value2});
    }
    else if (value1Set == -1)
    {
        sets[value2Set].Add(pair.value1);
    }
    else if (value2Set == -1)
    {
        sets[value1Set].Add(pair.value2);
    }
    else
    {
        if (value1Set == value2Set)
        {
            // duplicate entry, skip the add
            continue;
        }

        // merge the sets at value1Set and value2Set
        foreach (string value in sets[value2Set])
        {
            sets[value1Set].Add(value);
        }
        sets.RemoveAt(value2Set);
    }

    uniquePairs.Add(pair);
}
```